# adding 1 to a value using google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I developed a record entry form and I want to automatically increment the row IDs of the sheet where data resides on submission of each new record. cell value which I want to increment is half text and half number like PMNT00000001 I need a function that can make it PMNT00000002 on next record submission and so on. I have written the following code.

```
 function myFunction() {
  var newDocId = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(), 3).getValue();
   sheet.getRange("B2").setValues([newDocId+1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what your sheet may look like -

[image: test-sheet]

Try this -

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var regex = /(\D+)(\d+)/g;
  var lastRecord = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
  var split = regex.exec(lastRecord);
  var prefix = split[1];
  var serial = parseInt(split[2]);
  var addOne = serial + 1;
  var newSerial = ("00000000" + addOne.toString()).slice(-8);
  var newRecord = prefix + newSerial;
  ss.appendRow([newRecord]);
}
```

Feel free to modulate the number of 0s and the value of `slice` which has currently been set to `-8`, based on your OP.

Hope this helps.